# repeating a drawing attached to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, how can I make the repeated cubes attached to each other vertically and horizontally to make a one solid block?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{cube}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\newsavebox{\hh}
\savebox{\hh}{
\newcommand{\Depth}{1}
\newcommand{\Height}{1}
\newcommand{\Width}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,\Width,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,\Width,\Height);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0,\Height);
\coordinate (D) at (\Depth,0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (\Depth,\Width,0);
\coordinate (F) at (\Depth,\Width,\Height);
\coordinate (G) at (\Depth,0,\Height);
\draw[blue,fill=yellow!80] (O) -- (C) -- (G) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=blue!30] (O) -- (A) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!10] (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.6] (C) -- (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (A) -- (B) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make it looks like this

[image]

Comment: I think it would be easier to do it _all_ within a `tikpicture`.  Part of the problem is that you have spurious spaces after `\savebox{\hh}{` and the `\newcommand{\Depth}{1}` (similarly for the other two `\newcommand`.  Need to add a `%` there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it. The spaces between the blocks of the cubes are removed, but not the spaces between the individual cubes. I also added \hskip -.32cm and \vskip -.36cm between \foreach commands

Comment: Yes, that was only part of the problem. When you are placing the black _outside_ of the `tikxzpicture` you are effectively placing boxes next to each other just as you do with letters. Thus, you would need to add negative horizontal and vertical spaces to get the desired alignment. However, then you have the lower pictures on top of the upper pictures, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: This solved the distances between the blocks. How about the distances between individual cubes within each block?

Comment: Adding a negative horizontal space should resolve the horizontal spacing.

Comment: Where, in the code, the negative horizontal spaces should be added.

Comment: Have added an answer to illustrate the negative horizontal and vertical spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Peter Grill, if you use a `tikzpicture` for that you can do what you want. I think your approach of using `\savebox`es here is one way to go but the more Ti*k*Zy way would be to use `pic`s here. This trades the `\newcommand`s for parameters of the cubes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
cube/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{code={
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,#2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,#2,#3);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0,#3);
\coordinate (D) at (#1,0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (#1,#2,0);
\coordinate (F) at (#1,#2,#3);
\coordinate (G) at (#1,0,#3);
\draw[blue,fill=yellow!80] (O) -- (C) -- (G) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=blue!30] (O) -- (A) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!10] (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.6] (C) -- (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (A) -- (B) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle;
}}}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{cube}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1} 
{\pic at (\x,1,-\x-1) {cube={1/1/1}};}
\foreach \x in {0,...,2} 
{\pic at (\x,0,-\x) {cube={1/1/1}};}
\foreach \x in {0,1} 
{\pic at (\x+1,-1,-\x) {cube={1/1/1}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also achieve the same using `\savebox`es (which might be even a bit faster to compile). I also removed the spurious spaces, big thanks to Peter Grill!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{cube}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\newsavebox{\hh}
\savebox{\hh}{%
\newcommand{\Depth}{1}%
\newcommand{\Height}{1}%
\newcommand{\Width}{1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,\Width,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,\Width,\Height);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0,\Height);
\coordinate (D) at (\Depth,0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (\Depth,\Width,0);
\coordinate (F) at (\Depth,\Width,\Height);
\coordinate (G) at (\Depth,0,\Height);
\draw[blue,fill=yellow!80] (O) -- (C) -- (G) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=blue!30] (O) -- (A) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!10] (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.6] (C) -- (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (A) -- (B) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1} 
{\node at (0.9*\x,0.9,-0.9*\x-0.9) {\usebox{\hh}};}
\foreach \x in {0,...,2} 
{\node at (0.9*\x,0,-0.9*\x) {\usebox{\hh}};}
\foreach \x in {0,1} 
{\node at (0.9*\x+0.9,-0.9,-0.9*\x) {\usebox{\hh}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterGrill Good point! Fixed it. (IMHO there is no good reason to have these `\newcommand`s in the savebox, but I kept them there.)

Comment: Agreed, but one reason to have the `\newcommands` there and not outside may be to limit the scope and not interfere with similar names used elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterGrill This is certainly a good point. (However, in order to know where to place the cubes, I needed to know that these lengths are all 1 and the OP is using `scale=1`. This suggests that one may go a somewhat different route, in which one uses `pics` and makes these parameters arguments `#1`, #2` and so on. Yet I am not sure if the OP likes this path...)

Comment: Yes, using a `pic` would be the way to go.

Comment: How can I use the pics

Comment: @Hany I just added a `pic`s solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is to answer the question in the comments as to how to do this with negative spaces. I am *not* recommending using this solution though.  This images looks *wacky* as the bottom cubes are on top of the upper cubes.

Using a `tabular` is a bit easier so that option is provided as well.

[image]

## Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{array}%            \newcolumntype
\usepackage{tikz} 

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\hspace*{-0.90em}}c<{}}

\newsavebox{\hh}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{cube}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\savebox{\hh}{%
    \newcommand{\Depth}{1}%
    \newcommand{\Height}{1}%
    \newcommand{\Width}{1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (0,\Width,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,\Width,\Height);
        \coordinate (C) at (0,0,\Height);
        \coordinate (D) at (\Depth,0,0);
        \coordinate (E) at (\Depth,\Width,0);
        \coordinate (F) at (\Depth,\Width,\Height);
        \coordinate (G) at (\Depth,0,\Height);
        \draw[blue,fill=yellow!80] (O) -- (C) -- (G) -- (D) -- cycle;
        \draw[blue,fill=blue!30] (O) -- (A) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;
        \draw[blue,fill=red!10] (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
        \draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
        \draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.6] (C) -- (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;
        \draw[blue,fill=red!20,opacity=0.8] (A) -- (B) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%% ---------------------
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}\hspace*{-0.90em}}\par\vspace{-2.3ex}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}\hspace*{-0.90em}}\par\vspace{-2.3ex}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}\hspace*{-0.90em}}\par\vspace{-2.3ex}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {\usebox{\hh}\hspace*{-0.90em}}
\par
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}B@{}B@{}B@{}}
    \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} \\[-2.9ex]
    \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} \\[-2.9ex]
    \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} \\[-2.9ex]
    \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} & \usebox{\hh} \\[-2.9ex]
\end{tabular}%
%\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```